# Creating WordArt text effects -FabricJs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricJs to create wordArts where one can scale, rotate, transform the texts.
The approach would be rotate and skew every character in text at a certain angle.
I am using Itext class of fabric to style each character
here is what I have done but it isn't working.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')

var text= "Test fabricJs"
var comicSansText = new fabric.IText(text, {
fontFamily: 'Comic Sans',
left: canvas.width/4, top: canvas.width/2 ,
stroke: '#ff1318',
strokeWidth: 1,
strokeStyle:"#fff",

styles:[[{"fill": "red",
          "fontSize": 20,
          "angle":30,
          "transform":"rotate(30deg)"}]]
});
```

Refer fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/swesh/c7s9x2fh/

Comment: I enter the fiddle and I see that it is working... each object you add into the styles list it changes a character's design... what is the problem exactly

Comment: Hi I want to achieve this functionality 

basically I want to rotate each character at a certain angle so that the text string appears to form a rainbow.
http://www.simonkarman.nl/projects/html5_wordart

Comment: I don't think you can do that because as I've looked the angle property is inherited from the object class... and the styles property of IText class is used to manipulate each character but that doesn't mean the characters inherit from the object class thats why none of the transformation properties work on them. What I suggest is that you just create each character as its own object and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Curved text, you've to add fabric.CurvedText.js. 
[Download fabric.CurvedText.js](https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText)
After that, you can set the angle.

Its working for me.